# Using an IP-Address in URL to HTML Linked Resources (CSS, ...)

Tags: html, performance, http, dns

A well-known technique is to link resources (CSS, JavaScript, ...) with a separate DNS name for various reasons. Like this:

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com/
GET http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css
```

(Two different domain names)

Instead:

```
GET ...
GET http://92.60.242.2/stackoverflow/all.css
```

(One DNS lookup)

This means that **two DNS lookups** are required. Couldn't we just use an IP address instead of `cdn.sstatic.net` in order to save one DNS lookup?

Please assume that it is possible to use an IP host from the point of view of the server. Assume, that there is a dedicated resource serving server with a dedicated IP.

Comment: You can do that if you want.  However, one DNS lookup is not expensive, but the cost of using an IP address is potentially fairly large.  You lose virtual hosting (multiple sites per IP), DNS load balancing (multiple IPs per site), and when your IP address changes (since 100% uptime is fiction) you'll have to do extra work.  There are better ways to shave milliseconds of your load times.

Comment: In general I agree but beware DNS lookups can be expensive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content delivery networks usually employ some sort of load balancing, often implemented at the DNS level (e.g. the name `cdn.sstatic.net` resolves to different IP addresses, based on the geographical location of the requester). Hard-coding the IP address would be counter-productive, as the request will always go to the same server (which might still be a load balancer in front of several backend servers, but all of them will be in the same location).

Comment: Ok, what if no external CDN was involved? Just add an IP to the NIC of your own server if you have a spare one.

Comment: Of course, if you control the server this way you can do whatever you like. Keep in mind that you're mostly saving the time for a _single_ DNS request per visitor, since most (and probably all) browsers keep an internal DNS cache.